# Windows 10 with Pen Ctrl or Ctrl + Win Tooltip stuck

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-onenote

I'm using OneNote during the meeting and am a bit frustrated with this strange behavior of my tablet: When I place my palm on the screen to start writing, there is a 30-40 % chance that the pen indicator on the screen starts indicating Ctrl is pressed or Ctrl+Win is held for some reason. My tablet doesn't have a keyboard or an external keyboard attached. Once this happens, I have no option but to reboot and pray it doesn't happen again.

**Hardware:**

- Lenovo ThinkPad 10 (Type 20C1, 20C3)
- Intel Atom Z3795 Processor (1.59GHz)
- 4.0GB RAM
- Windows 10 Ent Build 18219
- 10.1in 1920x1200 Multitouch
- *WACOM Pen*
- Intel HD Graphics

All drivers are upto date.

Comment: We should make sure you not install any third party software before the issue occur. They turn off other application and check if the issue occur. Update system to the latest version to check too.